# jQuery - Image path replace folder error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have client specific images in many .html pages and I want to redirect the images path to other folder from default folder.

> I am trying to achieve the same by following code from **external
>   javascript file** which is **working as expected**. But getting an error and HTML source still showing as old file path

I am getting an error as below though Images are loading

`GET file:///E:/User/Images/test.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

PS: I am doing this scr

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(function () {
    var img = $("img");
    img.each(function () {
      var src = $(this).attr('src');
      if (src.indexOf('Images/') > -1) { // Default path of the images
        $(this).attr('src', src.replace("Images", "Images/client")); // New path
      }
    });
  });
});
```

And also, if I check source code, still it is showing as `Images/test.png` instead of `Images/client/test.png`

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN, why you redirected him to that page, have you read his code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be ,

```
$(this).attr('src', src.replace("Images", "Images/client"));
```

Comment: Sorry @all... it was typo with `client` text... I have corrected in question and in my code, still not working...

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to use a web server instead of what you are doing,

GET file:///E:/User/Images/test.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

means you are open the file locally.

However, your code is correct and doesn't have any error, you are trying to replace the word (client) with (Images/client) and because your src doesn't contain any word (client), the replace is not taking a place, your correct code should be something like:

```
$(this).attr('src', src.replace("Images", "Images/client"));
```

This will work for sure, test and let us know if it worked.

Thanks.

Comment: tried from web server as well, still no luck... and also typo corrected in my question and code

Comment: are you sure you don't have any error that prevents jquery from loading? cause I tried it just now on my server and it works fine

Comment: also, please post the error code here, and make sure you have this path exisit: Images/client with all images inside

Comment: I have cross verified in code and html page, test.png is loading from the Images/client... but still getting the error

Comment: sure you will get it, because the image is first loaded from Images/ after everything is ready, then you are making the changes

Comment: but if the image is correctly replaced, then we can work on how to get this error disappears

Comment: **@Ray A**.. thank you... our client is thinking, application has lot of .js issues, though we have explained the scenario to him... That is the only concern now, otherwise I should have ignored it :)

Comment: Sure, hope everything will work fine with you, also, don't forget to close this with accepted answer, for the help of the other who will visit this page after you.